# How to return a tuple of ReturnType of a method in the interface which is a type of variable arguments

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'd like to finish to write a method looks like below. The interface `A` is a config type for generators I'm going to have different configs with different types of generators and use them at once in the function `f` in order to get all the generated values in a tuple.

```js
interface A<Output> {
   f: () => Output;
};

const a: A<string> = {
   f: () => 'Hello',
};

const b: A<number> = {
   f: () => 42,
};

function f(...x: ???): ??? {
   return x.map(x => x.f());
}

const y: [string, number] = f(a, b);
console.log(y) // ['Hello', 42]
```

How can I achieve this without any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can represent the function as a type acting on a generic [mapped tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).  If the output is a tuple of type `T`, then the input is of type `{[I in keyof T]: A<T[I]>}`, meaning: for each index `I` in the `T` tuple, the input should be of type `A<T[I]>` and the output is of type `T[I]`:

```
function f<T extends any[]>(...x: { [I in keyof T]: A<T[I]> }) {
    return x.map(x => x.f()) as T;
}
```

Note that the compiler is not and might never be able to verify that `x.map(...)` actually produces a value of the expected type; even representing such a transformation in general would require something like *higher kinded types* which are not currently supported in TypeScript (see [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) for a relevant feature request).  The easiest thing to do is what I've done above: just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that the output will be of type `T`, by writing `x.map(...) as T`.

---

Let's make sure it works:

```
const y = f(a, b); // [string, number]
console.log(y[0].toUpperCase()) // "HELLO"
console.log(y[1].toFixed(2)) // "42.00"
```

Yep, looks good.

---

Oh, and you *can* represent this transformation as something using the [`ReturnType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype), but it's more cumbersome to write:

```
function f<T extends A<any>[]>(...x: T) {
    return x.map(x => x.f()) as { 
      [I in keyof T]: ReturnType<Extract<T[I], A<any>>["f"]> 
    };
}
```

It behaves similarly from the caller's side, though.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIB4AqA+ZBvAKGWORgC5kAKASmQF5dMBuAgXxYIQHsQBnMZHAoZ+UUAHNcdfERLkqtBsgDkACQgAbDV2UAaNh258BAI2HoQAVwC2J6FJklSFGvVwAWAEz72BAjEsQBDBgHlIsZAgAD0gQABNeQRAATwBtAF1sSgA6XKiKPGRUgElkUGQAawhkrhhkTHTzTBLM5FZaQicoCDBLKBBkKOzrOAAHSii3QeyYGlo4ROY2P04efmRk+lJKOF1kE2omZAB6Y6LRCT2rW2h01b4uDQhs7XFKNIAGdOywLgBVUajaAAYQWEDmJzOACJVABRAAy8IA8lD7rxHs9Xu9UgBGb6-ABiwCiEDilE81Fop2QUK82Q+H1RBBAcGsEF4o0QKAASj1MMkgY45IFgqEBjAItFYgk0Og4ClsBksrlsvl6h1ZE5iN1ev1piNxpMlENZpTBIlCiUygMqjU6g0KLzdSB+UD0LCYlBEGAsC09hh5clsIqoTAoa1fE5WH4nEZ1ptpLNdvtDpDzmAxCBxFcbHYoHdY2sMS8uG9Pvj-oCQWCIdSYQjkajCw8niWy7iK0SSWSKVToXSGajWEA)